# Rectifying two errors in School Library Management program in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, user-defined-functions, turbo-c++

I was looking for a *Library Management System*  program on which to make a school project. I found a good one on internet. The code can be seen here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/68713/153350   on code review stack exchange. I'm planning to making my project on it.

So, I ran the above code but it shows 3 errors. One's regarding multiple declaration of a variable, which I was able to rectify.

But I don't understand what to do about the other two errors.
 They both occur in the following line of code in the body of the function, void write_student():

```
 f.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
```

The first error says:

```
Undefined symbol 'st'
```

and the other says:

```
Could not find a match for 'ostream::write(undefined, unsigned int)'
```

Can someone provide help on what's wrong and how I can fix those errors? 
Thank you.

Comment: The second error stems from the first, for sure; it will disappear as soon as `st` gets resolved, so my first suggestion is to focus on the first one.

Comment: Where is `st` intantiated? `st` obviously must be an instance of the `student` type.

Comment: it's not `st`... it's `s`, man...

Comment: Note- I first asked this on code review stack exchange. And there when I wrote the full code in the question, the question couldn't be submitted the reason being that "it was not properly formatted" and I didn't know what to do so I've linked to the question. If someone can edit my question to copy the code here I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Géza Török, wow, thanks! :)))  I edited that and the program seems to run perfectly! How did you even follow all that code so quickly and identify the mistake?

Comment: as @GézaTörök wrote, you have a typo here. `st` must be changed to `s`.

Comment: @MrReality: Sometimes it helps to understand what compiler states to you...

Comment: @MrReality please accept my answer then :) it's posted below

Comment: Thanks for the comments @ovanes! I checked that. After the correction the code runs without any error.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it not a reasonable question?

Comment: @MrReality Sadly, questions of please-find-my-bug type soon get downvoted, since they do not contribute to the common knowledge, but solve a one-time problem of one person.

Comment: @GézaTörök, but I think this does contribute to the common knowledge. It is one of the top results when one searches for "library management programs" but it has some mistakes because of which I got the errors. So IMO this page would definitely help anyone who looks for a way to get rid of those errors.

Comment: @MrReality true that... forsooth, I found it with your keywords easily: http://www.cppforschool.com/project/library-management-system.html

Comment: @MrReality btw... I don't see the point in overhyping some strictly purpose-built code, written in the style of a 5-yrs-old, that does not even compile. Seriously, why don't you guys just write your own?? I am totally sure you would get above... and further :)

Comment: @GézaTörök, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these declarations...

```
//***************************************************************
// Global declaration for stream object, object
//****************************************************************
fstream f, f1;
book b;
student s;
```

---

...and this function involved:

```
void write_student(){
    char ch;
    f.open("student.dat", ios::out|ios::app);
    do{
        s.create_student();
        f.write((char*)&st, sizeof(student));
        cout<<"\n\nDo you want to add more students...(y/n?)";
        cin>>ch;
    }while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
    f.close();
}
```

You pass `&st` instead of `&s` to `f.write`.
Substitute the line in subject with

```
f.write((char*)&s, sizeof(student));
```

in order to make it work.

Comment: Hey, I have another query. You explained that part of code to me. Is it allowed here to put a code as a question and ask to explain, say, the whole or a major part of the code (what is happening, which functions do what and how, etc.) ? I'm asking because even though I'm making a project on this code, I don't understand it!

Comment: Well, I guess it's not the page for that. It's more like a candidate for Stack Exchange code review... Btw.. Where's the guy who wrote it in the first place?

Comment: See the page I linked to, the OP claims to have written it. It's hosted on at least one other website too: http://www.cppforschool.com/project/library-management-system.html

Comment: @Peilonrayz finally someone well-informed :) Could you please point us to a proper service?

Comment: Try the source debugger within your IDE. Just about every Stack Exchange site will downvote you for lack of research. If you aren't using an IDE, well then you will just have to walk through the code with paper and pencil, or start using an IDE.